# How to pick a folder in an Activity which is not MainActivity

Tags: android

I have two Activities in an app, MainActivity and SecondActivity.

I wanted to pick a folder by using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` action in SecondActivity, but I never successed.

The native folder chooser will return the result to the MainActivity, and will never trigger the `onActivityResult` of both Activities. My needs are only success if I use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` action in MainActivity.

The following code is my sample

```
<-- Manifest.xml -->
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

.

```
// MainActivity
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags += Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

.

```
// SecondActivity
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)

        startActivityForResult(intent, SecondActivity.REQ_CODE)
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data) // Never run to here

    if (requestCode == SecondActivity.REQ_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val selectedFile = data?.data 
    }
}
```

So my question is, how can I assign the return target of chooser to SecondActivity instead of MainActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY), if set then `onActivityResult` will not invoke, which explains why it returns to your MainActivity afterwards. Remove the flag will solve the issue, but if you intend to keep it then you need to find another workaround.

> If set, the new activity is not kept in the history stack. As soon as
>   the user navigates away from it, the activity is finished. This may
>   also be set with the noHistory attribute.
>
> If set, onActivityResult() is never invoked when the current activity
>   starts a new activity which sets a result and finishes.

Comment: I misunderstood the meaning of this flag. Thank you so much.